# Implementation of ResNet50 SSD on keras

Tags: python, keras, object-detection

I am using this Single Shot Detector (SSD) [implementation](https://github.com/pierluigiferrari/ssd_keras) in keras which uses VGG16 (as the original version of SSD). I am interested in replacing the original backbone of VGG16 with ResNet50. Although this has been implemented before I could not find any source regarding the keras SSD resnet implementation.

Anyway, does someone knows where I can find this architecture? Basically my question regards at which feature extraction layers to attach the decision layer. Judging from the similarities between the two networks and for a typical image size (for Pascal Voc for example) `300x300` I would guess to apply decision layer after each repetition group of ResBlocks (i.e. before downscaling the feature map). I am not sure the names are universal in every ResNet implementation but anyway:

- After `Add3`  with size `38x38x256`
- After `Add7`  with size `19x19x512`
- After `Add13`  with size `10x10x1024`
- After `Add16`  with size `5x5x2048`

So, I would get 4 decision layers comparing with 6 on the SSD VVG original version.

Should I add more feature extraction layer to further decrease the feature map size and extract features from there also? Is this considered to be the typical architecture? If anyone has some knowledge over this please share it.